# Nginx 301 redirect a url with query string

Tags: web-services, redirect, nginx

I have page with pagination which google marked as duplicate content, basically I have this page `/asl/candidates/` and `/asl/candidates/?page=1` is the same page. What I want to do is to 301 redirect `/asl/candidates/?page=1` to `/asl/candidates/`

I tried

```
location = /asl/candidates/?page=1{
  return 301 /asl/candidates/;
}
```

But it seems it does not work with query strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$args` or `$arg_name` if you need to get the argument(s) in the request line.

For example:

```
if ($args ~ "page=1") {
    rewrite ^/asl/candidates/$ /asl/candidates/? permanent;
}
```

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables